# Python: variable naming convention - file, path, filepath, file_path

Tags: python, coding-style, naming-conventions

I would like to know the correct naming convention for the following variables in **Python** which I couldn't find one from [**Google Style Guide**](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Files_and_Sockets) and [**PEP8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

(Let's say I have the following Python code)

> output_file = open(output_file_path, 'w')

What would be the best variable name for the out file name?

I believe the possible options for the variable name would be something like

`output_file` `outputfile` `outfile` `out_file` `outfile`

And the **path** variable can be something like

`output_file_path` `output_filepath` `output_path` `out_path` ...

Comment: Underscore and non-underscore thing I understand in your question but in the last line its totally on you that you want to name your variable `output_path` or `output_filepath`

Comment: Whatever you and maybe others working in the code prefer.

Comment: Personally I prefer `output_path` and `out_path`. The others feel long winded, especially if you have multiple variables that define different output paths. Though if you're editing someone's script then I'd say consistency is key to follow their conventions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you should use `_` between each meaningful words for variable names, Similarly we use capital case for class names.
by searching about the word `filepath` I should say that there is not such a word in English, it means that it is not a single word, it contains two separate word(`file`, `path`), so it is correct to use `file_path` instead of 'filepath', although both of them is being used by developers these days.

About the part that contains `output` word, According two *Zen Of Python* we already knew that:

> Readability counts.

and

> Explicit is better than implicit.

I should say that is pretty much better to use `output` before your variable name. 
So I think `output_file_path` and ‍`output_file` are the correct and best choices here.

Answer (score 1):

Citing from https://english.stackexchange.com/a/428231/289175 :

> Both forms, filepath and file path, are used, but which one is used is often dependent on context. [...] filepath, as an unhyphenated compound word, is generally used when discussing it as an entity (e.g., “You’ll need to set the filepath before writing out any data.”), but file path, as two words, is generally used when referring to a particular attribute of a file.